# Autocomplete no longer works in cmd after the July Windows 10 update

Tags: windows-10, command-line

Since my last Windows update there were some features added to the command prompt cmd but autocomplete doesn't work anymore it only inserts a TAB character, does anyone experienced this behavior or knows how to fix it, it's annoying, thanks for any help.

I am using Windows 10 (10.0.18362.239) and the installed patches are `KB4506991` and `KB4507453`.

Comment: You will have to be more specific.  Which cumulative updatedid you install exactly?  What version of Windows 10 are you running?  What features were added exactly?  Please edit your question instead of replying with a comment

Comment: Hi @Ramhound I have added more info

Comment: `KB4506991` is a .NET Framework patch, if these issues were introduced due to that patch, you should simply remove the patch.  Have you tried to verify if the behavior exhibits itself without the patch in question?

Comment: Why did you remove which patch you installed from your question body, that was important information, that you removed?

Comment: @Ramhound I am not sure this patch caused the problem there were about three patches I will post those ones

Comment: First, it’s great you self-solved this issue. But the thing is you need to post an answer to present an answer open this site… Which you did. But please don’t edit your question to add the answer. Just post an answer and then—when you can—self select that answer as the answer and all is good.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found that I was missing a key in my registry that contains this settings. I don't know what caused the deletion of this key, the key was `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`.

Comment: If you were missing the root `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` key then you didn't have any of the subkeys.  You basically did not have command interpreter[Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)